# nxp microprocessor ethernet socket coding and sending code

Tags: ethernet, microprocessor, eeprom, debugging, socket

I have nxp [lpc43s50](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC43S50_30_20.pdf) microprocessor and I made an ethernet connection via lan8710 and at24c02 .I know how to connect at24c02 to my microprocessor pins .However I don't know how to send codes to  my processor pins and which codes to be sent.I have [a folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7yGzIXnDK8od01xMzdKZmZjdXc) consisting of driver and ethernet socket programs .However these code are not for nxp processors but nxp development and debugger boards.Please help me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ethernet pin programming in nxp microprocessor with lan8720](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325192/ethernet-pin-programming-in-nxp-microprocessor-with-lan8720)

Comment: ı asked this previous question but ı ask about  drive folder and what ı sould do.

Comment: Secondly ı  looked at the link you send me and ı learn a lot about I2C .

Comment: You completely ignored other questions asked by me and Peter and opened a new question almost identical to the closed down question.

Comment: Sorry that's  enterily my mistake  but ı am new . Therefore ı intented to ask new question and take fresher  answer:((

Comment: @optocoupler Check out the help center on how to write good questions, keep them specific and format them correctly.

Comment: This question and all of its answers are gold. Favorited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made some research and I could get the project code by using [this site](https://www.oryx-embedded.com/download.html) and downloading  the codes .In Nxp folder , I opened the lpcxpresso_4337 folder  and arm keil project inside of it .In addition , I changed driver codes inside the project  as lan8710.h  and  lpc43xx. Then I saved all the changes after modifying necessary items.You dont need to use at24c02 or etc .Because this processor  has already taken  1 spesific mac adress . Then you should use debugger like jplink etc. to send your code to your device .I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: why do you give -1   ? Do you have some mental problem?

Comment: ^ This exchange made my day.

Answer (score -2):

LPC microprocessor have specific I2C and Ethernet mac pins to be programmed so firstly you should find lan8710 driver code and you found as seen from your drive.

Secondly, you should program your I2C eeprom and you have already done this.

Thirdly you should define the pin configuration as code.

Finally you should define Ethernet interface code.

Finally you will send this code to the processor pins by using JTAG or any other debugger tools.

Then connect this processor to the lan8710  and I2C eeprom. It is not so easy as seen but you can do that .I don't know too much about your codes content maybe some other person can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I need is especially the content part .

Comment: ı wonder why you give -2 . İf you know the answer then tell us if you don't  , give +2.